# I can't get php errors to log to a custom log in CentOS 7.3 and PHP7

Tags: php, apache

I have in a php.ini in `public_html` that has

```
display_errors = on

error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

log_errors on
error_log  /home/account/public_html/error.log
```

`phpinfo` shows that the `php.ini` file in `public_html` is being loaded. The `error_log` file has 755 permissions and belongs to the same group:owner as all other files in `public_html`.

But, when I force php errors, no errors are displayed or logged. Errors are logged in `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`. And I've restarted apache.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you run the `phpinfo` it is from the apache instance, or CLI? I wouldn't put your error log in your `public_html` folder either.

Comment: phpinfo is viewed by web browser from public_html. The error log is only temporary for bug fixing; I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
log_errors on
error_log  /home/account/public_html/error.log
```

To

```
log_errors = on
error_log = /home/account/public_html/error.log
```

Next, near the top of your script, do:

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file(); // to make sure that you're editing the right php.ini
echo ini_get('log_errors'); // should be '1'
echo ini_get('error_log');  // should be path from php.ini
```

If the settings don't match what you set (I assumed you restarted Apache), check the rest of the `php.ini` as well as Apache VirtualHost configuration for another setting that may be overriding yours.

When you run`phpInfo()`, it will sometimes show a list of `ini` files that get loaded (not just your basic `php.ini`.  One of them could also contain an override.

Finally if none of that works, you could set error-logging in-script with `ini_set()`. Just be aware that if that script itself has an error, this setting may not have the chance to take effect so it's best to do it in a script separate from your main, and require it

**main.php**

```
require_once('./init.php);
// ... your regular script
```

**init.php**

```
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/errors.log');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `=` after log_errors; but also I looked at phpinfo and there was one other php.ini file that had display errors set to off. The way to `echo` the ini settings worked, too. There were many other ini files, but only one other php.ini.